# Tomcat sends incorrect error code if there is a 'partial' error code to error page mapping

Tags: tomcat, http-status-code-404, tomcat7, web.xml

I want to send a 401 error response back to the client and tomcat7.0.39 overrides that and sends 404 instead. What's causing this seems to be error-page definitions in web.xml.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errorPages/404.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/errorPages/403.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Commenting out all error mappings makes the problem go away. I guess when tomcat can't find something mapped to 401, it sends back a 404 not found. This means if a error mapping exists, then it needs to be 'complete'. This for me is strange design and has a huge consequence. If you don't know what error codes a tomcat context might return and have customized error pages for 404 and 403, you may need to provide all 100 4XX error pages. This makes life difficult for a PaaS vendor who provides tomcat with customized error pages and a mapping for them in the global web.xml. Has anyone been bitten by this? How would you handle such a scenario if you agree providing all 4XX error codes is ridiculous?

Comment: So, when you tell Tomcat that 403 errors should go to `/errorPages/403.html` and `/errorPages/403.html` does not exist, what do you think the behavior should be? If you configure your server improperly, why do you think it should work properly?

Comment: @Christopher Thanks for your comment, but I think you might have misread a few lines. I am telling tomcat to return 401 but it returns 404. 401 code does NOT have any entry in web.xml so I think just because tomcat fails to find 401 mapping on web.xml it returns 404 error page. Which part do you think is configured improperly?

Comment: What happens at the HTTP level when you send a 401? If you send a 401 and something is intercepting it and redirecting/forwarding to another resource that does not exists, then a 404 would be expected. Have you enabled the AccessLogValve? If so, what shows up there when you expect a 401 response? What about with/without your `<error-code>` configuration?